# How do I find occurrences of a String in a String Array?

Tags: arrays, swift, string

To give some context I am building an app that basically displays a bunch of calculations I made based on some JSON. For example, I found the Bible in JSON and want to find how many times a name shows up in the chapter text.

Here is the JSON of one of the books: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aruljohn/Bible-kjv/master/genesis.json

I have an array of Bible names, and I am searching through each verse in each chapter for a given bible book, finding the number of occurrences for each name.(Note: I haven't put in male biblical names yet)

```
var names = [String]()

let nameString = """
    Abigail
    Ada
    Ahlai
    Angel
    Anna
    Apphia
    Atarah
    Athaliah
    Bathsheba
    Bilhah
    Candace
    Chloe
    Claudia
    Damaris
    Deborah
    Delilah
    Diana
    Dinah
    Elizabeth
    Esther
    Eunice
    Eve
    Hagar
    Hannah
    Huldah
    Jedidah
    Jezebel
    Joanna
    Judith
    Julia
    Leah
    Lois
    Lydia
    Martha
    Mary
    Michaiah
    Milcah
    Miriam
    Naarah
    Naomi
    Oprah
    Phebe
    Priscilla
    Rachel
    Rebecca
    Ruth
    Salome
    Sapphira
    Sarai
    Sherah
    Susanna
    Tabitha
    Tamar
    Tirza
    Vashti
    Zilpah
"""
names = nameString.components(separatedBy: "\n")

func getData(){
    for book in bookNames {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aruljohn/Bible-kjv/master/\(book).json") {
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                if let jsonData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Book.self, from: data) {
                    bible[book] = jsonData
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func searchNames(_ verseText: String, _ name: String) -> Int {
    let array = verseText.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let nameCount = array.filter { $0 == name }.count
    return nameCount
}

getData()

//Notable Names
var dict = Dictionary<String, Int>()
for chapter in bible[bookNames[0]]!.chapters {
    for verse in chapter.verses {
        for name in names {
            dict[name] = searchNames(verse.text, name)
        }
    }
}

print(dict)
```

**How come when I print, every name says 0?**
Where did I go wrong? For sure the getData() functions correctly and actually returns text with the `verse.text` but it won't count the names.

Comment: It looks like some of your code is missing. Where is `bookNames` and `bible` defined. Aso, are you running this in a storyboard? Also... have you tried debugging to print out any intermediate values?

Comment: And the link you provided returns a 404. :-) a few updates to the question are needed I think.

Comment: I would start by trimming `names`. I am pretty sure they contains some white spaces in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Sulthan already told you what the problem is. You need to remove white spaces from names:

```
let cleanedName = name.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
dict[cleanedName] = searchNames(verse.text, cleanedName)
```

Comment: Even with names stripped, the names still don't populate. Also the links with the app